# Windows 10 desktop restarting for 1 user

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, desktop, user-profiles

Windows 10 constantly restarts the desktop for a select user.  The user cannot do anything but <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> and `logout`.  This does not happen for the administrator account on the same system.  I have tried booting in safe mode with same results.

Any recommendations where to start looking?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new user profile?

Comment: yes, i created a new user and that one worked fine.  I would like to recover the one in question and to also understand why this is only happening to one user account

Comment: Presumably his account is corrupted. Can he log in in safe mode?

Comment: Does [Corrupt User Profile: Fix for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10](https://neosmart.net/wiki/corrupt-user-profile/) help?

Comment: When log into the account after booting in safe mode the issue persists.  I reviewed the document listed above and I do not have a .bak reference in the registry.  In reviewing other documents about recovering a corrupt user the registry items are set as described.  Still desktop continually restarts

Comment: It might be possible that the user account is executing some command to restart the computer. 

Check the startup tab in task manager for that user, is there any entry for a program that you don't recognize. Disable the startup of all the unrecognized programs and restart.

Comment: The computer is not restarting, the desktop is.  I cannot check task manager because when the user is logged in the desktop restarting prevents anything else from being run.

Comment: Created a new user and recovered as many files as possible from troubled user.  It baffles me why in Windows the solution for most user issues is to create a new user.